# How can I validate my jQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I am looking for an online jQuery validator. Not a script that will validate my forms but an online tool with which I can give it some jQuery script and have it return syntax errors and other useful information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out jsfiddle.net.  You can paste in your Javascript, link in external libraries, and run your code through both a formatter and JSLint, which will identify any issues in the syntax of the code itself.

It also provides a preview pane to go through more thorough functionality testing.

Answer (score 3):

Try [jQuery lint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/). Quoting the website:

> jQuery Lint is a simple script you can download and use with jQuery. It works over the top of jQuery and diligently reports errors and any incorrect usage of jQuery. It will also, to some extent, offer guidance on best practices and performance concerns.

If you really need to use it online, you can do so on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: If anyone else finds this through google, notice that this jQuery Lint is outdated and not working with current versions of jQuery!